# Fix HTTP 504: Gateway Timeout when not using a load balancer

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, backend

I am developing an application which allows the user to download data from this remote database server. My server sode contacts another database server, get&package all the data, and send the data back to the client side. Everything works fine locally. However, when I deploy my code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I get a HTTP 504: Gateway Timeout, if my request doesn't get a respond in 60 seconds (when the data is too large and it takes more time to get all the data).

I have looked up a lot of posts online, but most solutions had to do with using a load balancer. I am not currently using a load balancer, and I am not really sure how to proceed with my issue. I know what I have to do is to change the timeout/idle limit, but I can't seem to find a resource that gives me insight on how to do that when I am not using a load balancer.

To give a main idea of how the project is built, it is written in ReactJS and Java, and it connects to a remote database server to request data. I am not using CORS/proxy, but using the Java backend code to have my server contacting the database server when I request for data. I am also using annotations in Spring framework for my requests (and more specifically, the controller class).

If you have any ideas on how to solve this issue, please let me know. I really don't know much about web application development. Thanks in advance!